# Do I need to install CoreData.framework even though I use CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, cocoapods

I've been working on my iPhone app and implementing Google Analytics on it.

I use CococaPods to install GA, and it seems to work fine so far in my simulator.

I found that document of GA, and now I'm wondering if I install the following 5 frameworks and libraries. They are not in my iPhone app now, but it works fine.

What are these 5 frameworks and libraries for?

- [Google Analytics Services SDK](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sdk-download)

  > The Google Analytics SDK uses the CoreData and SystemConfiguration frameworks, so you will need to add the following to your application target's linked libraries:
  >
  > - CoreData.framework
  > - SystemConfiguration.framework
  > - libz.dylib
  > - libsqlite3.dylib
  > - libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a

Comment: CocoaPods script might did it for you already, keep calm ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you see [HERE](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift), the guide doesn't mention these libraries when installing Google Analytics Services SDK with CocoaPods since the Pod itself is adding them for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If I use CocoaPods, I can not see these libraries on Xcode? (For sure I don't need to see them on Xcode, but I'm just curious why I can not see them on Xcode)